# Change Word Table Widths But Not First Row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to loop through every table in a Word document and change column widths. I found a macro to do this but it did not work because the first row in every table is merged.

Since I know that the second row and beyond are not merged, I tried to change the macro to skip the first row.

Here was my first attempt:

```
Sub MyAttempt()
    Dim t As Table
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each Row In t
          If Row.Index > 1 Then
            t.Columns(1).Width = InchesToPoints(1.2)
            t.Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(13)
          End If
        Next
    Next t
End Sub
```

I've since cleaned that code up to be the code below but it still gives me an error that it cannot change any cell widths because there is a merged cell in the table.

```
Sub MyAttempt2()
    Dim t As Table
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each r In t.Rows
          If r.Index > 1 Then
            t.Columns(1).Width = InchesToPoints(1.2)
            t.Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(13)
          End If
          Next r
    Next t
End Sub
```

Is there any way to jump over the first row which has merged cells and then change the cell widths on the rest of the table, doing so for every table in the doc?

Thanks for any help anybody can provide. Really appreciate it!

Comment: "Not working" means what exactly?

Comment: Tim, at this point, based on my revised code above, I am getting this error: Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub MyAttempt2()
    Dim t As Table, r As Row
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each r In t.Rows
          If r.Index > 1 Then
            r.Cells(1).Width = InchesToPoints(1.2)
            r.Cells(2).Width = InchesToPoints(3)
          End If
          Next r
    Next t
End Sub
```